# php syntax for echo javascript function

Tags: php, javascript, syntax

I hope somebody can help me with this little problem.
The problem is that I still get confused with the syntax

The php line echo's a javascript function that takes one parameter, the database value.

It needs to be corrected, to get it to work.
extra comma's??escaping?? I never know where exactly.

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r)){
     echo '<li onclick="fill(\''.$row["value"].'\');">'.$row["value"].'</li>';

}
```

**EDIT BECAUSE**
I just found out that my syntax is correct.
I just needed to include the backslashes.
It seems the javascript function is causing problems.
In particular the line that hides the list

**Does anyone has a solution for this?**

```
function fill(thisValue) {
    $('#inputString').val(thisValue);
   //$('#suggesties').hide();

}
```

**EDIT**
I finally came up with this: a callback

```
function fill(thisValue) {

     $('#suggesties').fadeOut('fast',function(){
        $('#inputString').val(thisValue);
    });

    }
```

thanks, Richard

Comment: Not sure I quite understand the "edit" part you added...

Comment: the function should fill the textbox with the value from the list ----the onclick function calls the fill function-- It seems that the hide function is faster then it can put the value in the textbox. I found out, when I commented out that line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo '<li onclick="fill(\''.$row["value"].'\');">'.$row["value"].'</li>';
```

Ouch. You've got a JavaScript string literal, inside an HTML-encoded attribute, inside a PHP string literal. No wonder the escaping is confusing you.

Well, first: you're outputting `$row['value']` in the list item's text without escaping. This means trouble (potentially security trouble) when that value contains special characters like `<`, `&` and `"`. This needs to be wrapped in `htmlspecialchars()`.

Next, you're putting something in a JavaScript string literal. That means if the string delimiter character `'` or the escaping backslash `\` is used in the value, it can break out of the string and inject JavaScript code into the page: again, a potential security issue. `addslashes()` can be used to escape a string for inclusion in a JS string literal; note you still have to `htmlspecialchars()` it afterwards because the string literal is itself inside an HTML-encoded attribute.

So we're looking at:

```
echo "<li onclick=\"fill('".htmlspecialchars(addslashes($row['value']), ENT_QUOTES)."');\">".htmlspecialchars($row['value']).'</li>';
```

Not very readable, is it? Well, we can improve that:

1. We can lose the PHP string literal by using PHP itself to interpolate strings (as demonstrated by Jonathan). PHP is a templating language, take advantage of that!
2. We can define a function with a shorter name than `htmlspecialchars`, which is a good idea since we need to use that function a lot in a typical template.
3. We can avoid the JavaScript string literal by having the JavaScript side read the data it needs from the contents of the list item (`text()`, in jQuery, since that's what you seem to be using), rather than having to wrap it inside an ugly inline event handler.

For example:

```
<?php
    function h($text) {
        echo(htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES));
    }
?>

<ul id="suggesties">
    <?php while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($r)) { ?>
        <li><?php h($row['value']); ?></li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#suggesties>li').click(function() {
        $('#inputString').val($(this).text());
        $('#suggesties').hide();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, I like the jquery way--Still, I keep having the same problem.--The list hides and the text is not in the textbox.--If I do not hide the list, it works??

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure you got the capitalisation of `id="inputString"` right? (And it is an `id` and not a `name`.) Post complete non-working HTML page?

Comment: @Bobince I actually did not needed solving of my question anymore, see question.
But with the security issues pointing out you where very very helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend also escape the string for use in javascript. `json_encode` does the trick. And the html part too, *if it's not supposed to contain html*:

```
echo '<li onclick="fill('.htmlentities(json_encode($row["value"])).');">'.htmlspecialchars($row["value"]).'</li>';
```

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` suffices in both cases.

Comment: Gumbo,not if string contains quotes. It will error-out at javascripting time.

Comment: @hacker: No, `htmlspecialchars` replaces `&`, `<`, `>` and `"`. And when the third parameter for quote style is set to `ENT_QUOTES`, `'` is also replaced. Only if the quote style is set to `ENT_NOQUOTES`, `"` is not replaced.

Comment: Yes, Gumbo, it will escape the quote effective at the time of parsing html attribute. Then the parsed code goes to javascript interpreter which errors out on something like `fill("a"b")`.

Comment: @hacker: But `htmlentities` doesn’t solve that issue neither.

Answer (score 1):

You could keep the PHP within PHP Tags. Sometimes it's easier than escaping numerous places:

```
<?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r)) { ?>
  <li onclick="fill('<?php print $row["value"]; ?>');">
    <?php print $row["value"]; ?>
  </li>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping like this:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r)){
 echo '<li onclick="fill(\''.$row["value"].'\');">'.$row["value"].'</li>';

}
```

Comment: seems like your $row['value'] contains double quotes or characters that creates invalid javascript. 

There are numerous occasions where i had to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around value so that you have `$row[value]` instead of `$row["value"]`.